# How to combine js and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display a div tag on click of one link like here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVEqe/7/).

But this wouldn't work, any brilliant suggestion please?

```
Sorry, I couldn't be able to copy/paste the code. SO doesn't accept long texts.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow. Did you even read the Bootstrap documentation?

Comment: @electr0hed, would you please link it ?

Comment: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the docs for bootstrap modals here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

To show a modal, you need to call

```
$('#rpopup').modal('show')
```

You should also remove the "hidden" attribute from the modal

You will also need to include the bootstrap javascript for this to work

Comment: that wouldn't work! would you please provide a jsfiddle link? 'cause that seems interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the documentation. Pending that, you could do something like this

```
$('#re').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#rpopup').css({
        'opacity': '1',
        'display': 'block'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thans for your answer, when I try this I get the popup only more than half displayed. why please?

Comment: It's because of the way the popup is positioned. Again, there is probably a better solution in the documentation, but you could do this: `$('#rpopup').css({ 'opacity': '1', 'display': 'block', 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'bottom': '0', 'margin': 'auto' });`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the attribute `hidden="false"` because the presence of that attribute will cause the div to still be hidden. You need to use `.removeProp()` instead of setting it to `false`:

```
$("#rpopup").removeProp("hidden");
```

However, note that IE won't read the "hidden" attribute, so your better off using jQuery `.show()` & `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/SVEqe/11/

1. You need include bootstrap-modal.js
2. fire event by `data-toggle="modal"` instead of `click` event.